# The name 'Inputname' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am a very very very basic programmer just starting off. I have followed a few tutorials and I am now trying to branch out into my own stuff but I keep getting the same Error that I cant rectify.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ///Call Method
        OutWelcome();

        ///Return the name from getname method
        Inputname = getname();

        Console.WriteLine(" {0}", Inputname);


    }

    public static void OutWelcome()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
    }

    public static string getname()
    {
        ///Declare Variable
        string Inputname;

        ///Prompt User
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your Name: ");

        ///Get name from user keyboard
        Inputname = Console.ReadLine();

        ///Returns name
        return Inputname;
    }


}
```

I keep getting the following error "The name 'Inputname' does not exist in the current context. Line 18, 17 and 19

I know the answer will be so simple its n00b worthy, but I am new and we all have to start somewhere.

Thank you in advance

Sean

Comment: Your `Inputname` local variable defined in your `getname` method. Your `Main` method can't see it. You can re-define a string variable in your `Main` method to keep the result of your `getname` method.

Comment: replace this: `Inputname = getname();` to `string Inputname = getname();`

Comment: Thank you for the swift replys, I have done as suggested but now I get the compile errors:-

1. Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

2. Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

3. Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct.

Sorry for being a pain

Comment: can you please update the above code again . You have a missing bracket somewhere . If you see your code, last line you have a '}' where is the opening for that ??

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    ///Call Method
    OutWelcome();

    ///Return the name from getname method
   string Inputname = getname();

    Console.WriteLine(" {0}", Inputname);


}
```

Comment: this could be a comment, not an **answer** @adityaswami89